# What is .Trash and .Trash-1000?

Tags: linux

Can someone tell me what these folders (.Trash and .Trash-1000) mean? They just appeared in my mountpoint and I'm wondering how?

Comment: To prevent the folder from being created, run `touch <folder_name>` in the parent directory.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Have a look at [How to prevent Ubuntu from creating a .Trash-1000 folder when deleting files from a USB flashdrive?](http://www.techportal.co.za/linux/161-how-to-prevent-ubuntu-from-creating-a-trash-1000-folder-when-deleting-files-from-a-usb-flashdrive).

According to the article, Ubuntu will create such folders when a file is deleted from a USB drive. Presumably this would allow a file to be restored if you accidentally deleted it.

In any case, the article offers the following recommendations to prevent a Trash folder from being created:

> Don't use the delete button only (Otherwise the .Trash-1000 folder will be created)
>
> Press the key combination shift+delete together to delete then Ubuntu won't create a .Trash-1000 folder. (Note: If you delete files and folders this way they are gone forever!)

Comment: Hi, 

Sorry I didnt explain the question briefly. I am using fuse mountpoint and not mounting a pendrive. Sorry, it was my mistake. I am reading the link you gave me. I hope it helps solve my issue. Thanks !

Answer (score 13):

For every mountpoint, Ubuntu creates a "Trashbin" as soon as you delete a file - so the file later can be undeleted.

The 1000 is the UID of the user that created the bin, so every user can have its own.

Comment: hmmm....Interesting ! Let me see if i understood right. When I delete a file in the mountpoint, It will be inside the same mountpoint and not to the general trashbin. And these are created only when I delete a file. Not by default when the mount point was created? Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

folders (.Trash and .Trash-1000).
These appear on whatever drives are accessed by any operating system based on Ubuntu. Ubuntu-based systems could be Mint, BlackLab, Zorin, Vinux, Peppermint, etc. The drives access by these operating systems could be any partition format: EXTx, NTFS, etc.

These .Trash folders could be small or large, depending on the deleted files created by the Ubuntu-based system.  Deleting these files can be another problem, especially in the Windows operating system, of any version, including the latest "insider" versions.